# See the files that will be deploy to Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm looking for way to make sure the files I deploy to Google AppEngine (Python) using `gcloud app deploy` are only the files I need.
In the log file it only list files that are skipped but not the files that are deployed.

Is there a way to see this list?

Comment: This can be helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064907/viewing-deployed-files-app-engine-standard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**All** the files and directories present or sym-linked under an app service/module directory (i.e. the directory where the respective service/module's  `.yaml` file exists) will be deployed when the respective app service/module is deployed, unless they're skipped files (i.e. they match the default or configured `skip_files` patterns - see the `skip_files` row in the `app.yaml` [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#syntax) doc table).

So you can obtain a recursive listing of your service/module directory (make sure you follow/include sym-linked sub-directories), then drop the skipped files from it.

Alternatively, if you are using `appcfg.py update` for deployment, you can use its `--noisy` option which will make it display, among other stuff, that desired info, like this:

```
...
09:31 AM Scanning files on local disk.
...
2016-11-25 09:31:28,131 INFO appcfg.py:2516 Processing file 'mail.py' 
2016-11-25 09:31:28,131 INFO appcfg.py:2657 Ignoring file 'mail.pyc': File matches ignore regex. 
2016-11-25 09:31:28,132 INFO appcfg.py:2516 Processing file 'main.py' 
2016-11-25 09:31:28,132 INFO appcfg.py:2657 Ignoring file 'main.pyc': File matches ignore regex. 
2016-11-25 09:31:28,132 INFO appcfg.py:2516 Processing file 'main.yaml' 
2016-11-25 09:31:28,133 INFO appcfg.py:2516 Processing file 'queue.yaml' 
2016-11-25 09:31:28,133 INFO appcfg.py:2516 Processing file 'templates/admin.html' 
...
```

Unfortunately I don't see a similar option for `gcloud app deploy`.

**EDIT:**

As of Google Cloud SDK 171.0.0 adding the option `--verbosity=info` provides you with processed files in a log line after it finishes uploading the files

`INFO: Manifest: [{'path/of/file/': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.project.appspot.com/hash', 'sha1Sum': 'hash'}, ...]`

Comment: so does that mean you cannot see the files deployed in the google cloud platform console if you used the `gcloud app deploy` option to deploy the app!?

Comment: i cannot find the files in the console (viewing the repository) that i deployed via terminal using the `gcloud app deploy` option, but i can see the files (viewing the repository ) that i cloned using through the console itself.

Comment: @FamicTech I suspect that's because cloning the repo in the console produces another repo with all its files, but deploying does't do that - it just uploads *some* of the repo content (the one which isn't skipped). And the deployed code is not normally visible in the console, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122249/google-cloud-how-to-deploy-mirrored-repository

Answer (score 18):

There is now a gcloud command to show this:
 `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload`.