# In Google App Engine, how do I get a list of files appcfg.py is uploading?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running into the famous Google App Engine "Max number of files and blobs is 10000" error. I have added a lot of `skip_files` arguments to my `app.yaml` file, but I'm not positive I've formed my regular expressions correctly.

Is there a way to get App Engine to show me a list of files it is cloning for uploading versus which files are being skipped?

Comment: post your skip files section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See the files that will be deploy to Google AppEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805182/see-the-files-that-will-be-deploy-to-google-appengine)