# Viewing deployed files app engine standard?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I go to Google Cloud Platform console / App Engine / Services, and under the Diagnose column click "Tools", then "Source", I get to a screen that says:  "Deployed Files".

Under the directory structure, it seems to me I only see non-deployed files.  For example I see my app.yaml file there.

How can I view the files that were actually deployed?

Seems like sometime in the past one could run "appcfg.py download_app" to download the deployed files, but that doesn't seem to work anymore, or at least I can't figure out how to specify an "Application ID" since everything now is in terms of services and project ids.

Comment: Your `app.yaml` file is a deployed one. Are you by any chance referring to the static files as the missing deployed ones?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  In this case I'm looking at a static website deployment of a web app, so everything is set as "static_files".  I was hoping for a way to make sure the files I set in my app.yaml were actually getting there as intended.  Possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App Engine stores and serves static files separately from application files. Static files are not available in the application's file system by default. This can be changed by setting the application_readable option to true.

Set `application_readable` in your app.yaml and redeploy your app, static files should appear in Debug

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true
```